# Auto-select "default" marker with Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I have a map with multiple markers plotted with addMarker/addOverlay. I would like one of these markers to be auto-selected when the map loads, and the map to center around it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by having the marker be "auto-selected"? Do you mean showing an InfoWindow for it (that's the little bubble with text sticking out of the marker)? If so, call [openInfoWindow](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker.openInfoWindow) on the marker and supply the stuff you want to be shown. I believe that will also pan the map so that the marker is shown.

If that doesn't pan the map like I think it should, you can set the center of the map using [setCenter](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.setCenter) on the GMap2 object.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem. I meant openInfoWindow :-).